# I am looking for software or a tool that can extract data of a screenshared video of someone writing code on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, research

I am running a human study of how programmers use a specific tool on Visual Studio Code. I recorded participants' screens during the session. However, during the video analysis faze I am doing, I am having to pause, play and rewind to get the following information.

TIME | EVENT | DETAILS_ABOUT_EVENT | OTHER_METADATA

For example, when they write code using a feature of the extension, I record it as:
12:39 | ACCEPTED_AUTOCOMPLETE | BEFORE | [image: Code Snippet before accepting autocomplete from VSCode Extension] | AFTER | [image] | START_LINE | 25 | END_LINE | 26

The goal of this is a finer-grained qualitative analysis of "What autocomplete suggestions are they accepting and rejecting?". Another coder is expected to follow the same process.

I am hoping there is a tool or software that can take in a video and extract some or all of the information I am manually coding right now. Or if that is not possible, a tool that can get one-second snapshots of the video for me and the time-stamp.